# Create a base that contains $x$ in a finite generated Abelian group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $A$ be a finite generated free Abelian group and $x \in A$ such that  $\forall y \in A$  $\forall n>1: x\neq ny $.

Prove that there is a base generating $A$ that contains $x$.

It seems simple and true, but I don't know how to formalize it. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "base"? A finitely generated abelian group is not necessarly free.

Comment: Diito. If B is a subset of A and B generates A then $B\cup \{x\}$ generates A. So we need to know the def'n of a base for a group.

Comment: it's free, otherwise "base" will not be well defined, sorry.

Comment: Then $A/\langle x \rangle$ is torsion-free and hence free, so $\langle x \rangle$ is a direct  summand of $A$.

Comment: why is $A/<x>$ torsion free? could you explain your answer formally?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof that $A/\langle x \rangle$ is torsion free. Otherwise, there exists $y \in A \setminus \langle x \rangle$ and $a, b \in {\mathbb Z}$ with $a>1$ and $ay=bx$. Let $c = \gcd(a,b)$.

Then $a=ca'$, $b=cb'$ with $\gcd(a',b')=1$, and $c(a'y-b'x)=0$. Since $A$ is torsion-free, this implies $a'y=b'x$. Since we are assuming that $y \not\in \langle x \rangle$, we have $a' > 1$.

There exist $\lambda,\mu \in {\mathbb Z}$ with $\lambda a' + \mu b'=1$. Now $x = (\lambda a' + \mu b')x = a'(\lambda x + \mu y)$, contradictig the hypothesis  $x \ne ny$ for $n > 1$.